# How can I check if an information is present or not in Excel file using Apache POI and Java Code

Tags: java, file, if-statement, apache-poi, import-from-excel

I have a question:

I'm reading some information from my Excel file using this Java code:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
try {
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
}catch (IOException ex) {
   ...
}

SummaryInformation summaryInfo = workbook.getSummaryInformation();

if (summaryInfo.getTitle() != null) {
    System.out.println(summaryInfo.getTitle());
}
if (summaryInfo.getAuthor() != null) {
    System.out.println(summaryInfo.getAuthor());
}
```

but I get this error I don't have the "Title" information:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have this error on this line:

```
if (summaryInfo.getTitle() != null) {
```

Now, How can I check if the "Title" value (or other value) is present or not if this condition give me an error?

Comment: Not all files have a Summary Information in them - did you try checking if the Summary Information itself is present (not null)?

Comment: I have tried to write this command:
System.out.println(summaryInfo.isSummaryInformation());
and I get a "NullPointerException" on this line.
What this result mean? This result for me is very strange because if I run this code on my first PC, it's work, but if I run the same code with the same file on my second PC, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You need to check if `summaryInfo` is null before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `summaryInfo` is not null.

```
SummaryInformation summaryInfo = workbook.getSummaryInformation();
if (summaryInfo != null) {
    if (summaryInfo.getTitle() != null) {
        System.out.println(summaryInfo.getTitle());
    }
    if (summaryInfo.getAuthor() != null) {
        System.out.println(summaryInfo.getAuthor());
    }
}
```